# Блочное линейное кодирования простым языком

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Нужен простой пример (в виде кода или нет - все равно) описывающий работу линейного блочного кодирования с проверкой на четность.
В интернетах (что на рускоязычной, что на англоязычной сторонах) нормального источника не нашел. Либо это конспекты/книги/etc. наполненные матаном так, что глаза в кучку сходятся, либо это примеры реализации кода Хэмминга, как в вариации "на пальцах", так и в вариантах готового кода.
Самое интересное, что Хэмминга я уже более-менее понимаю, а загвоздка в отличии его от обыкновенного блочного кодирования.
Все это нужно, для того чтобы я мог на примере обьяснить своими словами разницу между методами (реализацией их в коде) на экзамене.
Если кто-то поможет ссылкой или источником каким-нибудь - буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу цитату [отсюда](http://studopedia.ru/4_14890_lineynoe-kanalnoe-kodirovanie.html):

> При передаче цифровой информации, качество передачи часто оценивается
>   по числу искаженных бит из общего числа принятых. И так как невозможно
>   получить идеальный радиоканал, мы должны допускать определенное
>   количество искаженных бит и быть готовыми восстановить информацию или
>   в крайнем случае определить, что наличие ошибок не позволяет
>   использовать принятую информацию. Для обеспечения требуемых
>   характеристик в радиоканале с замираниями и используется линейное
>   (канальное) кодирование, которое подразумевает некоторую избыточность.
>   Кодирование, позволяющее распознавать и корректировать ошибки, можно
>   разделить на две категории: блочное кодирование и с исправлением
>   ошибок. Блочное кодирование предусматривает добавление к блоку
>   информации проверочных бит, по значению которых на приемном конце
>   можно определить достоверна ли принятая информация. Коды с
>   исправлением ошибок (корректирующие коды) позволяют исправлять ошибки,
>   вносимые радиоканалом. В GSM используется как блочное кодирование, так
>   и кодирование с исправлением ошибок. И в этом случае при приеме
>   информации в начале с помощью корректирующего кода осуществляется
>   исправление ошибок, если это возможно, а далее с помощью проверочных
>   бит блочного кодирования производится проверка: может ли быть
>   использована принятая информация. Порядок кодирования информации в GSM
>   представлен на рис.2.2. По степени важности кодовая комбинация в
>
> 260 бит разбивается на три блока: 50 бит, 132 бита, 78 бит. К блоку в
>   50 бит добавляются 3 проверочных бита, а к блоку в 132 бита - 4
>   проверочных бита. Далее первых два блока вместе с проверочными битами
>   кодируются кодами, позволяющими исправлять ошибки, и в результате мы
>   получаем 378 бит. Таким образом, мы имеем 378 бит закодированной и 78
>   бит незакодированной информации, которые образуют кодовую комбинацию в
>   456 бит. Эта кодовая комбинация характеризует сегмент речевого сигнала
>   в 20 мс и должна быть передана по радиоканалу. При этом требуемая
>   скорость передачи информации уже составит 22,8 кбит/с.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также стоит прочитать если не всю, то начиная со страницы 225 книгу Э. Таненбаума "Компьютерные сети" (5 издание)